# How to combine an .svg and a basic object in Openscad

Tags: openscad

As stated in the question I am trying to combine a drawing I have in .svg format with a simple cylinder in order to make a printable medal. I have tried the following code :

```
union()       {
    
translate([25,25,0]) cylinder(h=1.5,r=25,center=false);
translate([7,7,1.4]) linear_extrude (height=1.5) scale([0.2,0.2,1])  { import("/Users/tijg/Documents/projecten_actueel/3dwerk/eik/eikenblad-boom.svg");}
}
```

In the preview all looks well, but after rendering the drawing on top disappears. As I remove the cylinder, the drawing of the .svg renders perfectly and is printable. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you add images of the preview?

Answer (score 1):

you need to emboss the image either by raising the image or by increasing the height of the image. once it protrudes it will not disappear.